How can I mock the attributes methods in java?
Hi I am new to java and concept of mocking. I have a service layer method which look something like:
@Override
public synchronized String joinTournamentUser(long id){

    if(!tournamentTimeOfTheDay){throw new NotEnoughCredits("Not In a Tournament Time. Come back again when tournament starts.");}
    if(alreadyInGame.contains(id)){ throw new NotEnoughCredits("Already In Game"); } //check if already in a tournament


     int all = 0; // => if this hits 5, means all 5 countries exist in hashmap and will be ready to start a match.
     for(int z =0; z < UserServiceImpl.Country.class.getEnumConstants().length; z++){
        if(map.containsValue(UserServiceImpl.Country.class.getEnumConstants()[z].countryName)){
           all = all +1;
        }
     }

     if(all == 5){//matched
          return "Match starting...";
     }else{
          return "Waiting for match to start...";
     }
}

How should I write the unit test for this. I understand mocking, for example tournamentTimeOfTheDay is just a boolean belonging to Impl class.
Can I mock like,
@Mock
boolean TournamentServiceImpl.tournamentTimeOfTheDay;

then in the test methid.,
when(tournamentTimeOfTheDay.isAccessed()).thenReturn(true);

Same goes with alreadyInGame which is a List of integers, I want to mock it when my service decides to check with .contains(), I want it to return true. How can I mock this in my test method ?
I always see some repo methods being mocked but what about attributes of the class which can require some method checks like this ?

Do not mock attributes directly as it leads to tightly coupled tests, which may break your tests in the future. Instead, stub the behavior of the methods using it. Also, you will have limited control over the behavior of the attribute, in this case, directly mocking tournamentTimeOfTheDay might not allow you to define its behavior under different scenarios.

then I can write test cases for my service that do not include mocking at all, correct? I can also do that if that is accepted by general Java public @DamodarHegde

alongside the mocking tests

Whether you choose to use mocking or not depends on the specific requirements of your tests and the design of your application. Mocking is often used in unit testing to isolate the unit under test and control the behavior of its dependencies. Mocking can be useful when, for example, your service relies on external systems (databases, APIs), you can mock those to isolate your service's logic and test it independently.

I agree with @DamodarHegde This method under test doesn't really seem to require mocking from what I can tell. You should look at how the boolean field is being populated, whether this is from a property or another method etc and use that to test your multiple scenarios. I have previously also seen package level setters for these fields on the service class to allow the test to set these properties as desired. But there should be no need to mock that in this case
